# Django Rest Framework: Use DELETE on GenericAPIView without implementing Retrieve

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and want to be able to delete a Content instance via `DELETE` to `/api/content/<int:pk>/`. I *don't* want to implement any method to respond to `GET` requests.

When I include a `.retrieve()` method as follows, the `DELETE` request **works**:

```
class ContentViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Content.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        pass    #this works, but I don't want .retrieve() at all

    def delete(self, request, pk=None):
        content = self.get_object()
        #look up some info info here
        content.delete()
        return Response('return some info')
```

If I replace `.retrieve()` with `RetrieveModelMixin` it also works. However, if I remove both of these, which is what want to do, I get the following error.

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'content-detail' not found. 'content-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I haven't tested, but I assume the same thing would happen with `PUT` and `PATCH`.

My questions are:

1. How can I allow `DELETE` without implementing a `.retrieve()` method, and
2. Why can't DRF create the urlconf without `.retrieve()` implemented?

**UPDATE: Failing test and complete error traceback caused by removing `.retrieve()` method**

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIClient
from myapp.models import Content

class ContentTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.content = Content.objects.create(title='New content')
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_DELETE_content(self):
        url = reverse('content-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.content.pk})
        response = self.client.delete(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myproject/myapp/tests.py", line 548, in test_DELETE_content
    url = reverse('content-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.content})
  File "python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py", line 50, in reverse
    url = _reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py", line 63, in _reverse
    url = django_reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **extra)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 636, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'content-detail' not found. 'content-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: have you tried: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#destroyapiview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess here but did you use a `SimpleRouter` or a `DefaultRouter` to build your `urlpatterns`?

If so, that's your problem. The router uses a viewset and expects to have all methods implemented. More info [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#using-include-with-routers)

What you can do is just add your `url` to `urlpatterns` like you would normally do on django using the `.as_view()` method.

Comment: I did use a `DefaultRouter`. I will check and see the result

Comment: Your solution is the most direct, but the reason why I chose [GenericViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#genericviewset) was to incorporate auto-routing like normal DRF viewsets, without implementing any actions by default (so that I could pick and choose).

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How can I allow DELETE without implementing a `.retrieve()` method?

Just remove the **`retrieve()`** method from the view class. Which means, the [**`GenericViewSet`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#genericviewset) doesn't provide any ***HTTP Actions*** unless it's defined in your class.
 So, the following will be your code snippet,

```
class ContentViewSet(GenericViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Content.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def delete(self, request, pk=None):
        content = self.get_object()
        # look up some info info here
        content.delete()
        return Response('return some info')
```

or you could use **`mixin classes`** here,

```
from rest_framework.mixins import DestroyModelMixin


class ContentViewSet(DestroyModelMixin, GenericViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Content.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

---

> 2. Why can't DRF create the urlconf without `.retrieve()` implemented?

I'm not sure how you've defined your URLs. When I tried with ***DRF Router***, it's only creating the URL conf for defined actions.
You've got **`GET`** and **`DELETE`** actions on your end-point because of you'd defined the **`retrieve()`** method in your view class.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks but in my question I mentioned that I had already tried removing the retrieve() method... and the result was that delete() no longer worked because drf could not find the reverse url.

Comment: Are you sure  because, the reverse urls has no effect on DRF's delete method

Comment: And, i don't see any code snippet related to that problem in your given code as well as in the source code.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that a DELETE request to reverse('content-detail') only works for me if retrieve() method is present, else I get `NoReverseMatch` as shown in the question. I simply tested by including and then removing retrieve(). Was also able to use RetrieveModelMixin to same effect. Since my code passes the test, this is mainly a curiosity for now

Comment: can you add ***complete error traceback*** to the OP?

Comment: I've added the full traceback from the error caused by removing `.retrieve()`. As mentioned, this error goes away when retrieve() is implemented in some way.

Comment: @ZG101 Can you add `test_DELETE_content()` function which is located at `myproject/myapp/tests.py` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194222/discussion-between-zg101-and-jpg).

Answer (score 0):

My solution for part 1. is to include the mixin but restrict the `http_method_names`:

```
class ContentViewSet(RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['delete']
    ...
```

However, I still don't know why I have to include `RetrieveModelMixin` at all.